# CKEditor - Permission denied on setReadOnly in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am getting a permission denied error only in IE browser, on setReadOnly(). Looking deeping in ckeditor.js, it looks like the editable HTML body element is giving the permission denied error.

I've tried on FireFox and Chrome and both works fine.

Is this a known issue from ckeditor?

Thanks

Comment: forgot to mention, I'm using ckeditor 4.4.3

Comment: No, this isn't a known issue. But the place to ask would be on http://dev.ckeditor.com

Comment: I have the same issue in IE9 and 10, but not in IE11. IE's Console error reads: "SCRIPT70: Permission denied 
ckeditor.js, line 81 character 136".

Answer (score 4):

I've figured it out. I'm not sure whether you're trying to setData and then setReadOnly(true) but that's what I was doing. It seems the two commands were conflicting such that setReadOnly was trying to run while the value of the CKEditor was still being updated. I fixed it for IE10 by putting setReadyOnly inside the setData callback:

```
var newValue = "Whatever your new value is here";
CKEDITOR.instances["ck-edit"].setData(newValue, function() {
    CKEDITOR.instances["ck-edit"].setReadOnly(true);
});
```

Note that ck-edit is the id of my CKEditor instance:

```
<textarea id="ck-edit"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Internet Explorer and Edge with CKEditor 4.5.10. Putting setReadOnly() in a setData() callback fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I have solved juste using setTimeout, like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ this.element.ckeditorGet().setReadOnly(value) }, 100);
```